# Generics and TObject based T issue

Tags: delphi, generics

I have base class

```
  TWMapObject = class (TObject)
  private
    AFname: string;
    FFileHandler: TWMapFileHandler;
    function TryOpenFileHandler(const fName: string): TWMapFileHandler;
  public
    property FileHandler: TWMapFileHandler read FFileHandler;
    constructor Create(const fName: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
```

ancestor

```
  TBlpTexture = class (TWMapObject)
  public
    width, height: integer;
    id: GLuint;
    hdr: TBLP2Header;
    constructor Create(const fname: string);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure LoadBlp;
  end;
```

and T based manager

```
  TWMapObjectClass = class of TWMapObject;

  TWMapObjectManager<T: TWMapObject, constructor> = class
  type
    PManagerRec = ^TManagerRec;

    TManagerRec = record
      obj: T;
      ref: integer;
    end;
  private
    ht: TDictionary<string, PManagerRec>;
    function CreateNewT(const fName: string): T;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Add(const fName: string);
    procedure Remove(const fName: string);
    procedure Clear;
    function Get(const fName: string): T;
  end;
```

I want to use `TWMapObject` based classes as generic parameter `T`, for that helper function

```
function TWMapObjectManager<T>.CreateNewT(const fName: string): T;
var
  obj: TWMapObject;
  ct: TWMapObjectClass;
begin
  ct := TWMapObjectClass(GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T)).ClassType);
  obj := ct.Create(fName);
  Move(obj, result, SizeOf(pointer));
end;
```

called from

```
procedure TWMapObjectManager<T>.Add(const fName: string);
var
  pr: PManagerRec;
begin
  if ht.TryGetValue(fName, pr) then
      inc(pr.ref)
  else begin
    GetMem(pr, sizeof(TManagerRec));
    pr.obj := CreateNewT(fName);
    pr.ref := 1;
    ht.Add(fName, pr);
  end
end;
```

and manager object created as `TexManager: TWMapObjectManager<TBlpTexture>`. That code was working for `TControl` based objects like `TButton` etc and created exact `TButton` for example in prevous project

```
class function TLuaClassTemplate<T>.CreateNewT(AOwner: TComponent): T;
var
  Ctl: TControl;
begin
  Ctl := TControlClass(GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T)).ClassType).Create(AOwner);
  Move(Ctl, result, SizeOf(pointer));
end;
```

With TWMapObject I see `TBlpTexture` as value of ct, but called only constructor of `TWMapObject` instead of `TBlpTexture`. Am I doing something wrong? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a virtual constructor:

```
type
  TWMapObject = class(TObject)
  ....
    constructor Create(const fName: string); virtual;
  ....
  end;
```

You'll need a meta class type:

```
type
  TWMapObjectClass = class of TWMapObject;
```

In any derived classes, override the constructor:

```
type
  TBlpTexture = class(TWMapObject)
  public
  ....
    constructor Create(const fName: string); override;
  ....
  end;
```

Your generic class does not need the `constructor` constraint (which so far as I can tell is next to useless):

```
type
  TWMapObjectManager<T: TWMapObject> = class
  ....
  end;
```

And finally, implement `CreateNewT` like this:

```
function TWMapObjectManager<T>.CreateNewT(const fName: string): T;
begin
  Result := T(TWMapObjectClass(T).Create(fName));
end;
```

And here's a complete program proving the concept:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TWMapObject = class
    constructor Create(const fName: string); virtual;
  end;
  TWMapObjectClass = class of TWMapObject;

  TBlpTexture = class(TWMapObject)
  public
    constructor Create(const fName: string); override;
  end;

  TWMapObjectManager<T: TWMapObject> = class
    function CreateNewT(const fName: string): T;
  end;

{ TWMapObject }

constructor TWMapObject.Create(const fName: string);
begin
  Writeln(ClassName);
end;

{ TBlpTexture }

constructor TBlpTexture.Create(const fName: string);
begin
  inherited;
  Writeln(fName);
end;

{ TWMapObjectManager<T> }

function TWMapObjectManager<T>.CreateNewT(const fName: string): T;
begin
  Result := T(TWMapObjectClass(T).Create(fName));
end;

begin
  TWMapObjectManager<TBlpTexture>.Create.CreateNewT('Foo');
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Since `TWMapObjectManager` has a constraint on `T`, is the `TWMapObject` typecast really needed? `Result := T.Create(fName);`

Comment: There's no more concise way to do it, as far as I know.

Comment: Through `move` in `CreateNewT` helper was code suggested by Peter Below from TeamB it seems. But your suggestion also works.

Comment: I don't think much of that `Move`. The simple cast is much better. The compiler will verify that the two values on either side of the assignment operator are the same size so it's actually a safer technique than the `Move` if you wanted to be pedantic. Of course, both work and are semantically identical. Use the code in my answer.

Comment: I used your code since it more clear to understand. Thanks again.